# Nunit won't discover working non explicit tests Visual studio 2022

Tags: nunit, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have 3 normal and 1 explicit test but when I run my test using the Test Explorer window I get this output under "Tests" in the Output window

```
========== Starting test run ==========
NUnit Adapter 4.2.0.0: Test execution started
Running all tests in xyz.dll
   NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 1 of 1 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Explicit run
ExplicitMethod(03/10/2022 08:00:00,03/10/2022 16:00:00): OneTimeSetUp: 
NUnit Adapter 4.2.0.0: Test execution complete
========== Test run finished: 1 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in 462 ms ==========
```

*Note I'm using NUnit Adapter 4.2.1 instead of 4.2.0 so that's already weird

And this is how the Test Explorer window looks
[Test Explorer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA8Vj.png)

*Note the full blue test is the Explicit test that get's skipped like it should

This is a problem because it does seem to only discover tests which are explicit.

The tests I want to run are of course not explicit, here is an example

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(TestNameData))]
public async Task<float> TestName(DateTime start, DateTime end, List<CalculateHoursObj>? list = default)
{
    if (list == null) list = new List<CalculateHoursObj>();
    return await EmployeeService.CalculateOverTimeHours(start, end, list);
}
public static IEnumerable TestNameData
{
    get
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(TenthMarch8_2022, TenthMarch16_2022).Returns(8.0f);
    }
}
```

It fails to discover and/or run this test.

But curiously if I break all my non explicit tests by making the data non-static like this

```
public IEnumerable TestNameData
{
    get
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(TenthMarch8_2022, TenthMarch16_2022).Returns(8.0f);
    }
}
```

It of course breaks the test and when I run all tests it does actually discover all tests

```
========== Starting test run ==========
NUnit Adapter 4.2.0.0: Test execution started
Running selected tests in xyz.dll
   NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 2 of 4 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Non-Explicit run
NUnit Adapter 4.2.0.0: Test execution complete
========== Test run finished: 2 Tests (0 Passed, 2 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in 394 ms ==========
```

But even now it only runs 2 of the 3 broken non explicit tests and of course they all fail

I have looked up everything online for 1.5 hours and really can't find a solution.

Don't bother responding with "have you updated visual studio or the nugget packages"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was part of a bug the solution is to not use new `DateTime()` withing nunit tests or to have nunit test be discover with id's using the `<UseParentFQNForParametrizedTests>true</UseParentFQNForParametrizedTests> <UseNUnitIdforTestCaseId>true</UseNUnitIdforTestCaseId>` flags

This was a bug because it was not reported correctly in the output window and/or Error List window.

I've created an [Issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/972) on GitHub about this if anyone wants to read.

Now stop editing this post because it truly is answered and the Issue link which I included shows the valid, correct and readable answer by "OsirisTerje" whom explains it way better than I could.